# how to make "next" work in cgdb

Tags: linux, gdb, cgdb

If you read the cgdb [manual](https://cgdb.github.io/docs/CGDB-Mode.html) pressing F8 should issue the "next" command to gdb and inputting "next" works as expected in gdb, as well as in cgdb interactive mode. However, pressing F8 steps into a function on my system (latest arch for amd64), instead of stepping over it. How can this problem be solved? I'm using cgdb version 20170325.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a [bug](https://github.com/cgdb/cgdb/pull/132). Before the fix appears you can

```
vi ~/.cgdb/cgdbrc

:map <F8> in<CR><Esc>
```